# Changing data type for one class attribute causes a segfault during construction of a subclass object

Tags: c++, constructor, segmentation-fault, subclass

**This version of code works well:**

```
class Object
{
public:

    // Object( string name, string state ) <-- string version
    Object( string name, bool state )
    {
        this->name = name ;
        this->state = state ;
    }

protected:
    string name ;
    bool state ;
    // string state ; <-- string version
};



class Tool : public Object
{
public:
    Tool(string name):Object(name,state)
    {
        this->state = true ;

        //this->state = "true" ; <-- string version
    }
};


int main ()
{

    Tool* tool = new Tool("name") ;


    cin.get() ;
    return 0 ;
}
```

...but if I make the `state` attribute a `string` (and substitute lines of code with the nearby "string versions" which I commented out) then, after a compilation with no issues, the program gives a segfault at runtime.

There are no problems when creating base class objects.

The debugger outputs:

```
#0 0x45b74c std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::string const&) () (??:??)
#1 ??   ?? () (??:??)
```

Why does making the `state` a `string` cause problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Tool(string name):Object(name,state)
```

You're trying to use an uninitialized member `state` (the `protected` member of the base class `Object`) as the argument of the `Object`'s constructor, it should be initialized by `Object`'s constructor. Using an uninitialized variable leads to UB, means anything could happen. In your case it causes a segment fault when using `std::string`.

BTW: You should get a compile warning for it. Such as [clang with `-Wall`](http://rextester.com/XRBW93142).

```
source_file.cpp:28:35: warning: base class 'Object' is uninitialized when used here to access 'Object::state' [-Wuninitialized]
    Tool(string name):Object(name,state)
                                  ^
```

Comment: How does making `state` a `bool` make the problem to not appear?

Its invariant size or...?

Comment: @dziadek1990 `bool` is build-in type, while `std::string` is a class type, has non-trival constructor and complex inner construction. `bool` might be safer in this case, but UB is UB, nothing is guaranteed.